# how to setup prometheus and grafana for ECS - EC2 in dynamic port mapping in a private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-ecs, aws-devops

I need to setup Prometheus and grafana for ECS ec2 cluster here the main challenge, it should update automatically when task as delete or after restart rolling update, can you please any one let me now how to configure and  I don't want to use AMP(managed solution) and cloud watch

implementation issue.

if any one done this configuration please let know or send me any documentation